# Web-scraping JSON loaded site in python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a supermarket site. They site loads the items and relevant info using JSON.

I can do it perfectly if I manually fetch the URL to the JSON GET using the network tab in the dev options in chrome.

Two problems: every time I change the page/load more items, there is a new and different "endpoint"/JSON to the items and I couldn't find a way to cycle through those urls.

If I use just the site URL (not the JSON one I get from the network tab), which I can cycle through, I can't get the information since it uses JSON to load the data.

This works:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.masonline.com.ar/_v/segment/graphql/v1?workspace=master&maxAge=short&appsEtag=remove&domain=store&locale=es-AR&__bindingId=d62c820d-5adb-43a2-9d15-25ff4f3a6d2f&operationName=productSearchV3&variables=%7B%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%2240b843ca1f7934d20d05d334916220a0c2cae3833d9f17bcb79cdd2185adceac%22%2C%22sender%22%3A%22vtex.store-resources%400.x%22%2C%22provider%22%3A%22vtex.search-graphql%400.x%22%7D%2C%22variables%22%3A%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%3D%3D%22%7D"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser').text
data = json.loads(soup)

test = (data['data']['productSearch']['products'])

df = pd.json_normalize((test))
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,2,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25,26]], axis=1, inplace=True)

df.rename(columns={'productName': 'Nombre', 'brand': 'Marca', 'priceRange.sellingPrice.lowPrice': 'Precio'}, inplace=True)
df['link'] = 'https://www.masonline.com.ar/' + df['link']
print(df)
```

but since it is only the first JSON, it only loads the items from the first page.

So I can also find the data like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.masonline.com.ar/268?map=productClusterIds&page=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
script = str(soup.find_all('script')[18])[8:-9]
print(script)
```

I didn't continue using this last option because the data was unusable if I get it like that.
With this last one I also tried to make it close to a JSON data format (thats why I removed 8 and 9 from the str) but it still doesn't work.

So I think my best option is to use the first code, but I don't know how I can automatically get the JSON link (the one I get from the network tab in the dev options) for every page when I cycle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payload is base64 encoded Json, so you can do something like this (you probably need to update/compute `sha256Hash` once):

```py
import base64
import json

import requests


def get_payload(from_, to_):
    payload = {
        "hideUnavailableItems": True,
        "skusFilter": "ALL",
        "simulationBehavior": "default",
        "installmentCriteria": "MAX_WITHOUT_INTEREST",
        "productOriginVtex": False,
        "map": "productClusterIds",
        "query": "268",
        "orderBy": "OrderByScoreDESC",
        "from": from_,
        "to": to_,
        "selectedFacets": [{"key": "productClusterIds", "value": "268"}],
        "operator": "and",
        "fuzzy": "0",
        "searchState": None,
        "facetsBehavior": "Static",
        "categoryTreeBehavior": "default",
        "withFacets": False,
        "variant": "",
    }

    json_data = json.dumps(payload)
    base64_data = base64.b64encode(json_data.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")
    return base64_data


api_url = "https://www.masonline.com.ar/_v/segment/graphql/v1"

for page in range(0, 3):  # <-- increase page count here
    base64_data = get_payload(page * 24, (page + 1) * 24)
    query = {
        "workspace": "master",
        "maxAge": "short",
        "appsEtag": "remove",
        "domain": "store",
        "locale": "es-AR",
        "operationName": "productSearchV3",
        "variables": "{}",
        "extensions": '{"persistedQuery":{"version":1,"sha256Hash":"40b843ca1f7934d20d05d334916220a0c2cae3833d9f17bcb79cdd2185adceac","sender":"vtex.store-resources@0.x","provider":"vtex.search-graphql@0.x"},"variables":"'
        + base64_data
        + '"}',
    }

    data = requests.get(api_url, params=query).json()
    for p in data["data"]["productSearch"]["products"]:
        print(p["productId"], p["productName"])
```

Prints:

```
...

188189 Mayonesa Hellmanns Liviana Doypack 475g
22375 Ketchup Natura 500 Gr
15791 Fideos Spaghetti Marolio 500 Gr
191757 Café Instantáneo Nescafé® Dolca® Suave 170g
166102 Caldo Verdura Maggi® X 12u.
14340 Galletita Pizza Saladix 100 Gr
135083 Harina Integral Pureza 100% X 1 Kg
176220 Conserva De Arvejas Aliada 300g
23745 Lentejas La Española 400 Gr
189853 Pan Lactal De Mesa 315g
```

Comment: Hey! thank you very much, it worked great. I never used base64 encoded JSON so I will have to look into it.
Can I ask a follow up question? Where do you find in the site all the settings for the payload?

Comment: @justabeginner Just open the Network Tab in Web Developer tools and do  Base64 decode on the string you see in the URL. You will see all parameters there.